# Custom authorization attributes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, filter, asp.net-core, action, authorize

i'm working on asp.net core and i don't understand some things.
for example in mvc.net 5 we can filter and authorize action with create class from AuthorizeAttribute and set attribute to actions like this:

```
public class AdminAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Admin/Account/Login");
        }
    }
```

but in asp.net core we don't have AuthorizeAttribute ...
how can i set filter like this in asp.net core for custom actions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use authentication middleware and `Authorize` attirbute to redirect login page. For your case also using `AuthenticationScheme` seems reasonable.

First use(i assume you want use cookie middleware) cookie authentication middleware:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "AdminCookieScheme",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Admin/Account/Login/"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Admin/Account/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            CookieName="AdminCookies"
        });
```

and then use `Authorize`attribute with this scheme:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "AdminCookieScheme")]
```

Another option is using [UseWhen](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples/blob/cdc53b2a132b73bc10fd4dcbb91b169634a589a1/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Server/Extensions/AppBuilderExtensions.cs) to seperate admin and default authentication:

```
      app.UseWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/Admin"), builder =>
      {
          builder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
          {
              LoginPath = new PathString("/Admin/Account/Login/"),
              AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Admin/Account/Forbidden/"),
              AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
              AutomaticChallenge = true
          });
      });
```

And then just use `Authorize` attribute.

Comment: is there another way ?

Comment: If you mean another way without authentication middleware, i would say "no" for authentication purpose. But for branching(admin, default etc.) there may be another way such as `MapWhen`.